# このリポジトリの作動方法を教えて欲しいです。

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]以前Stack overflowで説明不足だと言われたのでもう思っていることやりたいこと全部話します。

https://github.com/thunyoubun/TTS-VTuberAI-Anime

上記リポジトリを作動させたいのですが今２つのことで困っています。

まずターミナルでcd リポジトリ名にdocker run 次にdocker compose upで作動させたいのですが引数が必要とログで言われておりREADMEには

> To run Voicevox: `docker-compose up -d` To stop running the containers:
> `docker-compose down` Don't forget to shut it down to reclaim your ram. This should only after you have stopped the containers and are done using the program. `wsl --shutdown`

と書かれていますがやはり引数が必要なのかdocker-compose up -dで作動させるとターミナルの%が消えてターミナル自体使えなくなります。(動かなくなる)
でDocker compose.ymlには

```
version: "3"

services:
  voicevox:
    image: voicevox/voicevox_engine:nvidia-ubuntu20.04-latest
    ports:
      - "50021:50021"
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: all
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

と書かれています。この場合引数はportsの50021:50021かなと思ってますがどうでしょうか？違うのなら引数を教えて欲しいです。

もう一つは実は過去に一度再起動して友達にどうやったのかは知りませんが（聞いたが本人自体覚えてなかった。）ターミナルでdockerが動いたのですがその時にCPUアーキテクチャが違うとログで言われました。CPUアーキテクチャのx86-64マシンが必要ならしいのですが変更方法がわかりません。Docker platfromでできるらしいのですがDockerの公式ページを見てもよくわからなかったんですよ。なのでDocker platfromでCPUアーキテクチャの変更方法を教えて欲しいです。私が持っているパソコンはMacbookです。で私自体プログラミング歴が短いのでできるだけわかりやすくお願いします。他にも試したことで聞きたいことがあればなんでも答えます。

Comment: Macbook だけではアーキテクチャが分からないと思います。

Comment: すみません。説明不足でした。(linux/amd64) は、検出されたホスト プラットフォーム (linux/arm64/v8) と一致せず、特定のプラットフォームは要求されませんでした 0.0sってログで出てきたんですよ。あとで文章を追加しておきます。

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/thunyoubun/TTS-VTuberAI-Anime/blob/4e1ae54ac2f33151306edd9b7451b8ac11570af5/docker-compose.yml#L5 を見ると https://hub.docker.com/r/voicevox/voicevox_engine が提供する Docker image のひとつを使っているのが分かります。しかしこの image は image 名に書かれているように NVIDIA 製の GPU が搭載されているコンピューター上でないと動きません。最近の MacBook には NVIDIA GPU は搭載されていないので、このままだと動かすことはできません。具体的には 2015 年からの MacBook には搭載されていません。

voicevox/voicevox_engine には CPU 版の image もあるのでそちらを使うように書き換えれば動くかもしれませんが、動作確認までは行っていないので分かりません。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます！私はずっとdocker platformについて調べていたとき、もしかしてと思っていましたが、やはりMacbookでは動かない感じなんですね。ありがとうございます。ではちょっと書き換えてみます。https://hub.docker.com/r/voicevox/voicevox_engine　のURLからCPUと書いてるところではなくGPUって書いてあるところをコピーしてDocker compos.ymlに書き換えるって感じですかね？あと前の質問でもnekketsuuuさんにはたくさん教えて貰ってとても感謝しているのでフォローします。Stack overflowのフォローを詳しくはよく分かりませんがTwitterのフォローみたいな感じかなって思ってます。

Comment: Docker の platform オプション (OS や CPU architecture) とは関係ありません。

Comment: それは私が言った「CPUと書いてるところではなくGPUって書いてあるところをコピーしてDocker compos.ymlに書き換えるって感じですかね？」に対しての返信ですか？それとも「私はずっとdocker platformについて調べていたとき、もしかしてと思っていました。」の返信ですか？

Comment: 後者です。前者は Docker の platform オプションとは関係ないです。

Answer (score 1):

該当の Docker イメージは (nekketsuuu さんの回答の通り) GPU が必要、とは別の話を補足として。

---

"CPU アーキテクチャが合わない" の部分については、質問者さんの過去の質問を見ると **M1 Mac** のようなので、amd64 のイメージはうまく動かないと思われます。

`voicevox/voicevox_engine` の `OS/ARCH` で `linux/arm64` を選択するか、以下のように Docker 実行時に `platform` オプションを使用する方法があるようです。

**参考:**
[M1搭載MacのDockerでMySQLを動かしてみる](https://gihyo.jp/dev/serial/01/mysql-road-construction-news/0167)

(たまたま MySQL を動かす例ですが、重要なのは `platfrom` 指定の部分です)

> M1向けのDocker for Macでは、linux/amd64向けのコンテナを動かすことができるので、platformオプションを使用して実行してみましょう。
>
> ```
> % docker run --platform linux/x86_64 -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password-d mysql:latest
> ```

> Docker Composeは、Dockerと合わせて開発環境の中でよく使われる事が多いと思います。Docker Composeで指定するときは以下のような形で追加します。
>
> ```
> version: '3'
> services:
>   mysql:
>     image: mysql:latest
>     platform: linux/amd64
>     environment:
>       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
>     ports:
>       - 127.0.0.1:3308:3306
> ```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！ターミナルコードまでありがとうございます。とりあえずDocker Compose.ymlを書き換えてみましたが動きません。どうターミナルで打ち込んだのかは説明欄に付け足します。どこが間違っていますか？